# Ncurses not supporting color

Tags: java, android, ssh, terminal, ncurses

I am writing an android SSH Client. I have a terminal object that controls the view and an SSH object to send commands to the server.

My problem is that the terminal displays in color during all sessions but when an ncurses application opens, (tmux for example), the terminal displays in black and white.

I was able to find this: http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#white_black
I am not really sure what that means. Can anyone guide me on more documentation on this, or if there are any open source Java clients that support this feature. I am not really sure how to fix this.

Comment: What is the $TERM type? The environment variable $TERM has to be set to a terminal type that ncurses recognizes as supporting color, so it can look up the correct sequences to send. (The reason you're seeing color outside of ncurses is presumably that some programs just blindly send ANSI sequences for the purpose, even without knowing the terminal type.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been getting frustrated with this for a while. I did an export TERM=xterm-256color and that fixed it :-) Now I just need to do that in the app automatically. Feel free to post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you launched the application without the TERM environmental variable set appropriately, and that meant that during the initialization routines the remote operating system believed it wasn't talking to a terminal that could support colors.

Now that you have it set correctly, your colors work.  Congratulations!  However, setting it inside the application is going to be quite a trick.  This is because it needs to be set before you application launches.  Otherwise, when the application launches, the low level libraries you are linking into will query the "environment" to see what kind of terminal it has, which determines what kind of terminal codes will be emitted by your application.

This all happens before you app launches; so, effectively, you can't really do it from your application.  However, the real solution is a bit more interesting.

SSH makes very few assumptions about the display capabilities of the remote machine.  The best way to "fix" this is to have the SSH client set the terminal type according to the SSH client's capabilities.  Check your ssh client configuration to see if you can pass in a "better" terminal type.

In fact, having the host operating system assume the client's capabilities will create issues; however, demanding that every ssh client be configured to hand off it's terminal capabilities properly can be logistically impossible.  So, you may want to strike a compromise.  On the ssh server machine, try dropping a "wrapper script" to launch the application with a color terminal script.  It would read something like

```
#!/bin/sh
TERM=xterm-256color
export TERM
exec launch-app "$@"
```

and be saved as `launch-app-color` or something similar.